# Как вычислить векторы воздействия, суммировать и вычислить итоговый вектор направления действия сил?

Tags: ios, spritekit

Я создаю космическую игру, в которой будет гравитационный эффект у черной дыры. Где бы какой объект не находился, черная дыра будет притягивать его к себе. Для объекта все бы векторы воздействия суммировались, и вычислялся итоговый вектор направления действия сил.

Я знаю класс [SKFieldNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/noiseFieldWithSmoothness:animationSpeed:) с методом [customFieldWithEvaluationBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/customFieldWithEvaluationBlock:), который позволяет вычислять все самому, но может быть есть способы сделать это иначе?

Я попробовал почти все типы полей класса [SKFieldNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/noiseFieldWithSmoothness:animationSpeed:), но все бесполезно.

1. Были различные побочные эффекты, которые меня не устраивали (будь то электрическое или магнитное поле, объект отскакивал от черной дыры, что совсем не похоже на то, что я хочу сделать).
2. Более того, движение с помощью [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/) (например, космической ракеты) не позволяет суммировать все векторы сил в дальнейшем (возьмем 
   `- (void)moveTo:duration:`, который не позволяет этого делать, даже когда сгруппируешь действия (хотя это и понятно, почему)) .

Как мне решить данную задачу?